# Linkedin not getting thumbnail image

Tags: wordpress, linkedin-api

Everytime i try to share a wordpress post in my Linkedin it doesn´t pick up the imagem in the article. Don´t have any problem doing this on Facebook for example and i think everything in the Open Graph Meta is correct because my source code says:

meta property="og:image" content="http://smartkiss.net/assets/online-ad.jpg"

The dimensions are more than  80 x 150 pixels as Linkedin recommends. Any idea why this might be happening ?

Thanks

Comment: did you solved it anyway. I'm struggling with it for a new website, it is working in twitter, whatsapp, telegram, but not in linkedIn

Comment: This answer helped me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29769054/linkedin-not-picking-up-ogimage

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible reason might be that LinkedIn takes image from **oEmbed** tag as it shown in [another topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57596958/10718392).

I faced with wrong image choosing by LinkedIn in my WordPress site. I found the problem by discovering URL by [LinkedIn post inspector](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/) and saw the next information:

[image: *LinkedIn shows image source*]

Answer (score 0):

Try serving your images in a .png format versus a .jpg format. I know of several people having the exact same issue and this always worked.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, it did not work. For example this post from yesterday have a png @ smartkiss.net/search-engine-marketing-essencial-aumentar-vendas/ and still no thumbnail when i share on Linkedin.