# Wrong image displayed by LinkedIn Open Graph

Tags: html, linkedin-api, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I'm trying to share http://gbgtechweek.com/ on my LinkedIn profile.

I have this meta tag:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://gbgtechweek.com/img/gbgtechweek_img.png" />
```

However, LinkedIn chooses to show another image from the page (http://gbgtechweek.com/img/goteborg00.jpg)

Is this because of the size, and how do I fix it?

I tried to update by using "?!" in the end, so LinkedIn would re-fetch the Open Graph data, but didn't work.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LinkedIn (shockingly and sadly!) [only use official partners](https://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/34327/) from http://embed.ly/providers for 'projects' on your profile. Open Graph only works on the LinkedIn feed/sharing updates area.

Otherwise, you can upload an assortment of filetypes to feature, but no way to explicitly to tell LinkedIn which image to use on the profile.

Embed.ly does [pick up open graph](http://embed.ly/docs/explore/extract?url=http%3A%2F%2Fgbgtechweek.com%2F) information on your site, but they don't prioritize the OG information. In fact, Embed.ly wrote a blog post that essentially [scoffs at the widespread use of Open Graph tags](http://blog.embed.ly/post/45149940133/expectation-why-embedly-does-not-always-use-m) for sharing and how users and large websites supposedly can't trust them.

EDIT:

To answer the comment:

You *can* reshuffle things on embed.ly, for example, by disabling your `background-image` while you add your website to your profile, or switching your `background-image` to the desired one just long enough for you to get the desired effect on LinkedIn. This isn't a guaranteed fix as LinkedIn may recache the project at a later (any!) time which will set it back to your `background-image`.

Comment: Can I in some way restructure the image or give it a property to make it the first in the array of images, at the moment the image I want is the second one..

Answer (score 4):

LinkedIn can take the image from tag named '**oEmbed**' despite og:image tag exists.

Here an exapmle:

```html
<link rel="alternate" type="application/json+oembed" href="https://www.s-sols.com/api/oembed/1.0/embed?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.s-sols.com%2Fhow-make-multipage-website">
```

And this JSON content contains ordinary image.

I faced with that problem in WordPress. The cure was to remove this tag as [described here](https://whatabouthtml.com/how-to-clean-up-unnecessary-code-from-wordpress-header-175):

```php
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_oembed_add_discovery_links', 10);
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_oembed_add_host_js');
remove_action('rest_api_init', 'wp_oembed_register_route');
remove_filter('oembed_dataparse', 'wp_filter_oembed_result', 10);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try refreshing the linkedin cache (for a specific link) here:

https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me, and the reason was that the filename of the image in the `og:image` tag had accented Unicode characters in it (e.g., `á`, `é`). LinkedIn must skip over filenames with those characters, because it was choosing another image on the page instead.

I changed the image filename to one without Unicode characters and it pulled in the correct image.